# R Regex Address match after /

Tags: r, regex, string

I am working on building an address matcher in R. I am stuck on matching unit address e.g "22/106 Homer Street". I want to be able to extract the 106

This is the correct regex : `(?<=\/)\d+`

Entering into R as

```
data$door_number <- str_extract(data$Property_Address,"(?<=\/)\\d+")`
```

comes out with Error:

> '/' is an unrecognised escape in character string starting `""(?<=\/"`

I have tried multiple combinations of slashes but cant seem to extract the desired result in R.

Comment: Hi [Sheetal Bhundia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10766923/sheetal-bhundia), please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: escape it, `str_extract("22/106 Homer Street", "(?<=/)\\d+")`

Comment: @RonakShah That duplicate is not specific enough, because I don't think the OP should even be using a lookaround here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Obviously, there are different ways to solve the problem but escaping the character gives OP's desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
   somestring<-c("22/106 Homer Street.")
      newstring<-sapply(strsplit(somestring,"/"),"[",2)
  myaddress<-sapply(str_extract_all(newstring,"\\d{3,}"),"[")
  [1] "106"
```

It might be less useful for a very large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your current approach, because only checking for a preceding backslash would match something like `ABC/123`, if it were to occur in some of your address strings.  As variable width lookbehinds are not supported, I would recommend matching the full term.  Using `sub`:

```
address <- "22/106 Homer Street"
sub(".*\\d/(\\d+).*", "\\1", address)

[1] "106"
```